# Tesseract .tr file empty

Tags: homebrew, tesseract, tiff

I'm trying to integrate text recognition into my app with TesseractOCR. I need it to learn a custom font. I have Tesseract installed on my Mac via Homebrew. I have a tiff file: `eng.scout-cond.exp0.tiff` that I'm converting into a ".box" file. When I run the command
`tesseract eng.scout-cond.exp0.tiff eng.scout-cond.box nobatch box.train.stderr`
It says `Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.1 with Leptonica`
Then generates a file called `eng.scout-cond.box.tr`

1. I don't understand why it's a .tr extension instead of the .box extension shown to me in tutorials.
2. When opening the .tr file in a text editor, it's empty.

What would be causing it to be empty?

[eng.scout-cond.exp0.tiff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkppd.jpg)

[The tutorial I'm following](https://michaeljaylissner.com/posts/2012/02/11/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine/)

Comment: Can you add a link to the tutorial you are following?

Comment: It's from 2012, some parts are probably outdated.

Comment: Can you guide me to a more accurate, updated version?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed a step, the command shown in the original post is to create a .tr file from the .box file and the .tiff file.

SOLUTION:
I used the command `tesseract eng.scout-cond.exp0.png eng.scout-cond.exp0 batch.nochop makebox`
To make the .box file. Then I ran the command in the original post.

Comment: and what was the result?

Comment: It produced the .box file as expected. See my edit.